# Datepicker for Bootstrap (select Week only and making it work in IE)

Tags: javascript, date, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, picker

I'm using this date picker:
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

2 questions:

1. Anyone know how to make it work in Internet Explorer? It just
   doesn't, try it.
2. How can I configure it such that it selects entire
   weeks? (if a person selects a specific day in the week, the value
   passed is the start of the week, it would also be good if it
   highlights the entire week on hover)

Comment: works for me in IE 7-9 but has css bugs in IE7

Comment: Yeah, it's fine in IE9 but has a lot of problems in prior versions.

1) CSS is screwed
2) You can't select dates (js problem maybe?)

Comment: How about a different bootstrap date picker, such as https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker which is an improved version of datepicker by eyecon.

You might also consider using HTML5's builtin datepicker by simply using

```
<input type="date">
```